# correct MIN, MAX and CASE statements

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I like to extract MIN and MAX values from the same column. As I am using Group By so I have to use min and max. If I just use the whole column, it gives me error that you have to use aggregate function with Group By

How can I do it

ValueA = MAX(ValueB) + MIN(ValueB)

what will be the correct syntax?

Anyone?

and second question is

How can I use 2 case statement in a situation like this

```
select

ValueA =  Case ValueC
      when ValueB then ValueC
      else ''
      End
      Case ValueD
      when ValueE is blank then ValueD is also blank  
      END

From TableA
```

using 2 case statement like above gives me 2 columns instead, I want 1 column
plus in second case statement I just wrote algorithm of what i want

How can I fix this code?

Comment: "I like to extract MIN and MAX values from the same column." Well, I like cats

Comment: Please post some sample data, the output you'd like to get, and the **exact** SQL you've tried so far that isn't working. Otherwise, it's very hard for anyone here to help you.

Comment: For the 2nd question, `CASE ... END, CASE ... END`, 2 columns you get. One `CASE ... END`, one column you'll get.

Comment: I provided the situation (Hohhi). When I use above syntax I extract nothing. Any replacement of it?

Comment: ypercode--yes i get 2 columns,  I like to have it in same column

Comment: The above code will not get you 2 columns. It will get you one syntax error.

Comment: Better follow Ken's advice. Post a few rows of tableA (5 would be enough). Then post what you want as output.

Comment: If you want a fix for a TSQL select that is throwing an error then post the TSQL select that is throwing the error.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this?:

```
SELECT
    MAX(ValueB) + MIN(ValueB) AS ValueA
FROM
    tableX
GROUP BY
    columnX
```

Comment: yes but it does not work.  I can just use ValueB because that is what I want but because I am using Group By, it gives me error that I have to use aggregate function. Can I replace group by with something else?

Comment: Please post the code you have that produces that error. You can edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

add column name in select clause by which u want grouping. I think it works and not give error

```
select max(valueB)+min(ValueB)as valueB,columnX from tbl group by columnX
```

Answer (score 0):

Question 1: 
Depends on that group by clause. Please paste the actual code you are using. 
If you want each ValueB for each columnX then add it to your group by i.e. 
    `group by columnX, ValueB`
Or if you just want each ValueB once. Then 
    `SELECT DISTINCT ValueB from tableX`

Question 2: 
Quite confusing description. Give example input and output data.
My best guess is you are asking for, if B = C AND E = '' AND D = '' Return C ELSE '' 
i.e.
    `SELECT CASE WHEN B = C AND E = '' AND D = '' THEN C ELSE '' END as A
    FROM tableA`

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this for the CASE?

```
  SELECT ValueA,

  CASE
  when ValueB = ValueA THEN ValueC
  else ''
  End as ValueC,

  CASE
  when ValueE IS NULL THEN ''  
  END AS ValueD
```

It is difficult to understand exactly what you need.  Could you please add the data you have (several rows) and what output you expect to get?
Most people do not like images of the data, but that is better than nothing. :-) Thanks!